# Cannot Run a PIG

Tags: mysql, hadoop, apache-pig

After I install Hadoop, then I install Pig. However, I have the following problems:
when i try to run a pig, it turns out there are obstacles in its log:

```
coba@dewi-laptop:/home/dewi/Work2/pig-0.8.0-cdh3u0/bin$ ./pig 
2011-11-23 10:15:20,865 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Logging error messages to: /home/dewi/Work2/pig-0.8.0-cdh3u0/bin/pig_1322018120859.log
2011-11-23 10:15:21,364 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to hadoop file system at: hdfs://localhost:54310
2011-11-23 10:15:21,715 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to map-reduce job tracker at: localhost:54311
grunt>
```

Answer (score 2):

The logs above aren't an obstacle.  It's Pig telling you it's connected to a jobtracker and namenode on your local machine.  If this isn't what you intended (ie, you wanted it to connect to a different namenode or jobtracker) make sure that the environment variable PIG_CLASSPATH includes the directory where your Hadoop xml files are stored.

Comment: After I received the answer above, I continued the installation with the command pigs 

grunt> DUMP LMT;c